# PhoneGap Android Plugin: ContactView error

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile for a new mobile app.

This plugin is used to call native contact view of Android so you don't have to inject contacts in HTML.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ContactView

I've followed the instructions properly but it doesn't work for me, whenever I try to run (after all the initialization routine) this JS on Android:

```
    window.plugins.contactView.show(
        function(contact) {
            console.log(contact);
        },
        function(fail) {
            console.log(fail);
        }
    );
```

It shows this error:

```
Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found
```

Can anyone help?

Note: I haven't used any PhoneGap plugin before.

Comment: Issue has been solved with this: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/05/installing-childbrowser-plugin-on.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/05/installing-childbrowser-plugin-on.html

The issue has been described here in details.